# Shortcuts Import Variable to Send Message

Tags: shortcuts-app

Is there a way to get a saved text into the **Shortcut** action **Send Message**?  I can park a text into the **Clipboard**, but I can't seem to grab that to be sent with this action.  It seems it needs to be hard coded, which is a major restriction.

Anybody have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On macOS, right click and Insert Variable.

[image: macOS Shortcuts: Insert Variable]

On iOS, select a variable from the bar above the keyboard.
The ‘Select Variable’ button allows you to choose the output of any action.

[image]

Comment: Bingo.  That entry should be a natural pull-down.  Didn't see that at all.